# grpc sync server limit handle thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, grpc

I use the grpc cpp example "helloworold" code to test limit handle thread. But I can't find any way to do it.

grpc version: 1.15

linux: ubuntu 16.04

I set the builder like this:

```
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MIN_POLLERS, 1);
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MAX_POLLERS, 1);
builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::NUM_CQS, 1);
```

set the handle like this:

```
class GreeterServiceImpl final : public Greeter::Service {
  Status SayHello(ServerContext* context, const HelloRequest* request,
                  HelloReply* reply) override {
    std::string prefix("Hello ");
    std::cout << "start " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    reply->set_message(prefix + request->name());

    //**** sleep 5s, keep this thread block ****
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    std::cout << "end " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    return Status::OK;
  }
};
```

I use the example client and call `SayHello` in 100 threads, and server log show the thread is created by 100 times.

In this test, is my test way wrong? or somethings miss setup??

Answer (score 3):

You can use SetMaxThread in this way:

```
grpc::ResourceQuota rq;
rq.SetMaxThreads(n);
builder.SetResourceQuota(rq);
```

It seems that a thread is needed for every completion queue. So if n=4 when you have 1 completion queue, 3 threads are remained for processing requests.

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is the sync API, which will initiate a thread per call. You can look at the async API to reduce the number of threads.